# How count distinct id from multiple table?

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have 4 tables with id and date.
How can I count distinct id in each table and group by date.
To better explanation:

First table:

```
1 | 01-11-2018    
1 | 01-11-2018     
3 | 03-11-2018
1 | 03-11-2018
```

Second table:

```
1 | 01-11-2018    
2 | 02-11-2018    
3 | 03-11-2018    
1 | 03-11-2018
```

And so on.

In result I need:

```
Date          | Count first table      | Count Second table|    
01-11-2018    |         2              |          1    
02-11-2018    |         0              |          2               
03-11-2018    |         3              |          4
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Whatis the datatype of your `Date` column ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is using a UNION ALL to stick the total unique id's together.

Then SUM the totals.

```sql
SELECT 
`date` AS `Date`, 
SUM(TotalUniqueId1) AS `Count First Table`,
SUM(TotalUniqueId2) AS `Count Second Table`,
SUM(TotalUniqueId3) AS `Count 3th Table`,
SUM(TotalUniqueId4) AS `Count 4th Table`
FROM
(
  SELECT `date`, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS TotalUniqueId1, 
  0 AS TotalUniqueId2,
  0 AS TotalUniqueId3,
  0 AS TotalUniqueId4
  FROM `Table1`
  GROUP BY `date`

  UNION ALL

  SELECT `date`, 0, COUNT(DISTINCT id), 0, 0
  FROM `Table2`
  GROUP BY `date`

  UNION ALL

  SELECT `date`, 0, 0, COUNT(DISTINCT id), 0
  FROM `Table3`
  GROUP BY `date`

  UNION ALL

  SELECT `date`, 0, 0, 0, COUNT(DISTINCT id)
  FROM `Table4`
  GROUP BY `date`
) q
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple. Your database is there to store and retrieve the data. Not to format it nicely. What you do is

```
select date, count(distinct id) from table1 group by date
```

Then you do the same for the second table.

The rest is done on application layer.